# How do students respond to the "roll call" and how do you pronounce it?

Tags: pronunciation, american-english, british-english

I have two questions.

In the UK, to do (or is it read?) a *roll call* is commonly referred to as "calling <del>out</del> the register". It's been so long since I was a child that I'm not absolutely sure how students responded. I think it was *"Present, miss/sir"*

I also seem to remember students just raising their hands. Are there different responses in the rest of the English speaking world?

Secondly, I am experiencing difficulty in pronouncing *roll call*. I can say each word separately without any trouble but when I join the two together it sounds as if I'm saying "rolkol"; "rolekol" or "rol kol" I've looked in [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/roll_call) and [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/roll+call) but neither have the pronunciation. Should I pronounce *roll* in "roll call" as /rəʊl/ or /roʊl/?

EDIT

It seems responding to the roll call with "*present*" has become dated both in the UK and the US whether it holds true for Canada and Australia is unknown. Apparently, British students responded with "*Yes, miss/sir*" until the 70s but now the simple, "*Here*" is heard on both sides of the Atlantic. The *Longman Contemporary English Dictionary*, claims that [call/take the register](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/register_1) is old fashioned in the UK, but I wonder if that really is the case, and whether in the US "calling the roll" is becoming dated as suggested by the Google Ngram chart in @bib's answer.

Comment: 40 years ago in the UK it was definitely "Yes, miss".

Comment: Ahh, @AndrewLeach was it?! So when did "present" become more accepted?

Comment: /rəʊl/ and /roʊl/ are IPA for the British and American versions of the vowel in *bowl, hole, soul, toll* (which is pronounced slightly differently on either side of the Atlantic).

Comment: @PeterShor why am I finding it difficult to get my tongue round this? :) Try saying it fast, how does "roll-call" come out sounding? Must I take a pause?

Comment: Mari-Lou A, in my experience of secondary schools, this was known as *registration*. "Calling out the register" was in primary schools.

Comment: It was called 'taking the register' when I was at school. I think we just said "Yes, sir/miss".

Comment: TheMathemagician, it was also called 'taking the register', in my primary school days. Schools weren't very consistent then.

Comment: In suburban LA, the standard response was "huh?"

Comment: In my experience, contemporary Canadian usage varies; *yes, yup, yeah, here, present, uh-huh* are all quite common, and sometimes a student will say something entirely different.  It is usually called *taking attendance.*

Comment: I always responded "Absent!" and returned to my novel.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I don't think one can be that definitive. In my central Scottish Primary and secondary schools from the end of the 60s into the start of the 80s I had teachers who would mark you absent if you didn't reply in their preferred format. For some it was a silently raised hand, for some it was 'here, Miss', for some it was 'Present' and for one it was 'Yes, Mr Tweedie'.

Comment: In any case, only the call would be pronounced differently. But seriously, Mary-Lou A, are you really asking this question?? It seems to me that a native English speaker asking this is ever so slightly disingenuous.

Comment: When I was in sixth grade our teacher didn't call our names at all, he had us all just say "present" one after another in the order our names were in the roll (alphabetical). Made it fun for us.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the US, the most common answer is *Here*. While *Present* was also heard in the 1950s and earlier, this has largely disappeared except in smug exaggeration.

There are slight variances in regions across the US with a more significant *oh* (as in *bowl*) heard in the Northeast, and less so in the Midwest.

SUPPLEMENT: *Calling the roll* was used in schools through the late 20th century, and *roll call* is still used in the military and uniformed services, such as fire and police, and in legislative bodies (as in a *roll call vote*). Since the 1980s, the phrase *taking attendance* has become more common, as reflected in this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=taking%20attendance,%20calling%20the%20roll%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,taking%20attendance;,c0;.t1;,calling%20the%20roll;,c0).

Comment: This was exactly my experience (30 years ago when last I was in that position). I understand in some parts of the country (Philadelphia?) "Yo" can be used.

Answer (score 4):

As there are a few anecdotal answers here, here's mine (which is more recent - I left Sixth Form a few months ago) - for a **state school** in the **UK**:

"*Yes/Here Miss/Sir*" is the usual reply (obviously the "*yes/here*" isn't linked to whether it's "*Sir*" or "*Miss*").

I've never actually heard anyone speak of *calling* the register - it was usually referred to (by students and staff alike) as either "taking" or "doing" the register. I never encountered another way of referring to it, so I certainly wouldn't call "taking" dated at all.

If anyone did ever answer with a "*here*" (as occasionally happened lower down the school) they'd get a raised eyebrow and a long silence until they added a "Sir" or "Miss" to the end.

I've never heard "roll call" used (irl).

Comment: Nice to know that things haven't changed much in 35 years (especially the pregnant pause and the raised eyebrow!)

Comment: Broadly reflects my experience c.35 or more years ago as well. However, we rarely said "yes". Just "Sir". I'd be surprised if that wasn't the case in some UK schools still.

I remember in one registration a fellow pupil answering "present" but as a wind up (it could get very boring) which shows that the term was known but considered obsolete then.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I don't know about English schools but in Scotland, more specifically Aberdeen/Aberdeenshire, we say "here." In our school registration is a time to chat and get ready for the day, and because our teacher is quite forgiving, pupils tend to joke about and say "here/here miss," in a funny accent. Registration lasts seven minutes where we read the bulletin (school news). In posher schools in Aberdeen, pupils are required to say "present." All in all, it simply depends on the type of school/ area you are thinking about. Hope this helped!

Answer (score 2):

In [an episode of Endeavor](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6763274/?ref_=ttep_ep6) (set in Oxford in the sixties?) there is a boy's school where students would call out **adsum** in response to a roll-call. [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/adsum) lists it as follows:

> rare 
>   ‘I am here’ (used to indicate the speaker is present). Hence as noun: this statement as an answer in a roll-call, etc.
>
> Origin
>   Late 16th century; earliest use found in Taming of a Shrew. From classical Latin adsum, 1st singular present indicative of adesse to be present.
>
> Pronunciation
>   adsum/ˈadsʊm//ˈadsʌm/

By the way, I recommend watching the episode to get the full atmosphere. The scene is quite captivating.

Comment: I went to school in the 60s/70s not far from there, as a boarder, and we answered "Ads" to the roll-call (short for Latin "adsum"). I suspect that the practice continues today. On occasion, if there were no masters present at the evening meal, the prefect calling the roll would have had so much practice that the list of names assumed its own rhythm, and he would try to rattle through it at breakneck speed, with all the boys getting their "Ads" in as fast as possible while a colleague timed him. I can't remember what the fastest time was, though.

Comment: Covering for an illicitly absent friend by calling their "Ads" for them was also common, and largely ignored by the prefect, who marked them present even if the voice sounded wrong. No idea if the masters knew this went on, but hey, it was the 60s. We felt we could call the shots.

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember if we said 'present' or 'yes'.

'Roll' is pronounced as in 'bread roll', or 'roll out the barrel'. 'Call' is just as you would say 'call out when you are ready'.

Comment: Yes but bread roll is it; 'rol' or 'role'? Is the o short or open?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Open. Pronounced ROWL. I am thinking that Americans may give it a short O, which is unusual because they are obsessed with the open-type of O. You know, how they say YOO-GURT.

Comment: @WS2 As an American, I've never heard anyone say "yoogurt'. At least in the Northeastern US (PA, NY, NJ, New England), **roll** is pronounced with o as in owe.

Comment: @asfallows Well, I've never heard any American say yoghurt, the yog rhyming with log, as we do in Britain. They always seem to say 'yoo gurt'

Comment: @WS2 I'm reading "yoo gurt" with yoo pronounced like yew, do, or through. The most common pronunciation (at least in regions I've live in) pronounces 'yo' as in owe, know, or throw. If that's what you meant, then you've got it. We do not pronounce it the British way, in either case.

Comment: Could you please ask your Mancunian grandchild if his teacher "calls the register" or "takes the register"? I'm quite curious to know. I'm sure it used to be "call" in my day... I think!?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I will ask him tomorrow. But if it were me I think I would 'call' the register. I have just remembered when I went to grammar school in the 1950s, a member of the class was designated to check who was absent, if anyone, at the first lesson of the morning and the first of the afternoon. (We sat in rows in alphabetical order). He wrote the names (of absentees) on a slip of paper, signed by the teacher. The designated pupil then carried the slip to the school office. No one 'called' nor 'took' the register. I cannot remember what happened at Primary School. That was too long ago!

Comment: WS2, I got the impression that you meant that Americans pronounce the first part of the word *yogurt* in a way that rhymes with the first part of the word *yo-yo*. That is different from how British people pronounce it because, Americans (and Canadians) don't have the same, shorter O sound that is in British pronunciation and, many other languages.

Comment: @Tristanr That is exactly what I meant. They pronounce the 'yo' in 'yoghurt' as in 'yo-yo'. We pronounce the 'yog' to rhyme with 'log'.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I checked with the boy (8 years) and he tells me that in his school his teacher 'takes the register'. They answer by saying 'good morning' or 'good afternoon', which they can either do in English or in some other language if they choose. In his particular school (54% of children from non-English-speaking homes), some will respond in their family's language.

Comment: Thank you, it's quite interesting to know that pupils can reply in their native tongue. Not sure if I agree with the school's policy, but as the children are small I suppose there is no harm.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I am sure the reasons are social more than educational. But as they are leaning Spanish in the class, they are especially encouraged to reply in Spanish too.

Answer (score 1):

In 1968 in the UK we said, "here, sir" when the schoolmaster called the roll.

Comment: That sounds very familiar too. Are there any references or sources which you could quote from? Thank you. And your headmaster didn't "call the register" he called the *roll*?

Comment: Ollie Jones, was that in a private school? In my experience of state schools, there was no such thing as *masters* or *rolls*.

Comment: Well, yes, they called it a "public school," but in fact it was private. This particular one catered to expatriate yanks like me.

Comment: We yanks used to answer "yo" sometimes. But it was dangerous to tease those schoolmasters.

Comment: I thought so, Ollie.

Comment: Direct Grant School, Manchester, 1960s: "Sir!" (or sometimes "Miss!" after that historic day in 1967).

Answer (score 1):

In my time in secondary schools in England, in the last decade, it was common for students to respond with a simple *sir* or *miss*, depending on the teacher, during registration.

This was not called *calling* or *taking the register*. It was just called *registration*. It meant everyone in a class going to their form room and the form teacher filled in the register. It was done in the morning, before lessons and in the afternoon, before going home.

Comment: Could you add where and when?

Comment: In England, in the last decade.

Answer (score 0):

An excerpt from the play *Babies* by Jonathan Harvey, a young Liverpudlian playwright, who had previously worked as a teacher in London. The Royal Court Theatre of London first staged the play in 1994.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In India, the simple n routine routine way to respond a roll call is "yes/present, sir/mam". In our school we use the word 'presenty' for a roll call or taking attendance. As a teacher , today, I 2 use d same words. Suggest me something better n a new way for that. Dhanyawaad..!

Comment: 'Suggest me' is non-standard in the UK and USA, Sachin. And textspeak is not considered acceptable (unless the focal point) on ELU.