# Am I thinking of "Roll Call", or something else?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

"On the [missing word] were only kids from rich and connected families, who chose the school for its high level of education, but more so for the extracurricular activities and skills which were taught"

I'm looking for something to say - 'the list of kids attending a school'. I remember there should be something with "roll" in it.

TIA

Comment: I suspect you're thinking of "rolls" -- "On the rolls were only the kids ...".  If it's for a single class or group, vs a whole school or other assemblage then "roll" might be used.

Comment: In Britain we would say *register*. At the beginning of the day the teacher *calls the register* to see who is there and more importantly, who isn't.

Comment: (And, of course, "roll call" or "calling the roll" simply means to call off the names on the roll.)

Comment: Related (old question of mine) :) [How do students respond to the roll call?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147752/how-do-students-respond-to-the-roll-call-and-how-do-you-pronounce-it)

Comment: @Mari-LouA saw it, but didn't think I'll get my answer there ;)

Comment: Another potentially relevant term is _roster_ ("a roll or list of personnel," where _personnel_ can mean simply "persons," according to Merriam-Webster). The term for enrolling at a college is _matriculation_, so you could alternatively use the phrase "matriculation rolls."

Comment: @SvenYargs - Yep, "roster", in this context, means pretty much the same as "roll".

Answer (score 1):

*On the **[roster](https://www.google.com/search?q=roster&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)***

ros·ter /ˈrästər/ noun

> 1. a list or plan showing turns of duty or leave for individuals or groups in an organization.
>
>    a list of members of a team or organization, in particular of athletes available for team selection.

Answer (score 0):

I would venture that you are indeed thinking of "roll call." In an academic setting, "roster" or "attendance" would be appropriate. "Attendance sheet" would also work.

Comment: See [the definition of roll](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roll), the noun, 1b and 1c.

Comment: It's just *roll* or *rolls*.  *Roll call* is when you actually call out the names on the roll (generally for taking attendance).